# pegar e setar valor de um JDateChooser

Tags: java, swing

Eu criei um `JDateChooser` propio, para que eu possa fazer alterações mais personalizadas nele posteriormente.

O problema, é que eu percebi, que se eu escolho uma data nele, ele so me seta a data atual. Por exemplo, se eu escolher 1990 ou 2020, ele vai me retorna a data atual, e em uma formato diferente do `"dd/MM/yyyy"` que eu defini.  Tem alguma forma, de fazer ele apenas pegar e setar no formato de `"dd/MM/yyyy"`?

Minha tentativa:

```
import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class BackGr extends JFrame {

    JDC data = new JDC();
    JPanel painel = new JPanel();

    public BackGr() {
        setSize(450, 100);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        painel.add(data);
        data.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 20));

        JTextField f = new JTextField();
        painel.add(f);
        f.setEditable(false);
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));

        JButton btSetar = new JButton("Clique");
        painel.add(btSetar);
        btSetar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 20));

        btSetar.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            Date valor = data.getData();
            f.setText("" + valor);
        });
        add(painel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BackGr bg = new BackGr();
        bg.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class JDC extends JDateChooser {

    public JDC() {

    }

    public void setData(Object valor) {
        setDate(((Date) valor));
    }

    public Date getData() {
        JDateChooser calendario = new JDateChooser(new Date(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
        return (calendario.getDate());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que causa esse erro é seu método `getData()`:

```
class JDC extends JDateChooser {

    public JDC() {

    }

    public void setData(Object valor) {
        setDate(((Date) valor));
    }

    public Date getData() {
        JDateChooser calendario = new JDateChooser(new Date(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
        return (calendario.getDate());
    }
}
```

Repare que você retorna a data atual nele. Se o objetivo é resgatar a data do componente, use o método nativo `getDate()`.

Outra coisa, essa classe JDC não está seguindo a convenção de nomenclatura do java, é interessante sempre segui-la para evitar tornar seu código confuso.

---

Para que o retorno do método `getData()` seja no formato de uma data `dd/MM/yyyy` você precisa converter para string e formatar, pois o tipo `Date` sempre retorna no formato "[Unix Epoch](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Unix)"(ex.: `Wed Sep 13 16:51:55 BRT 201`). Para isso, basta editar seu método conforme abaixo:

```
public String getData() {
    Date dt = this.getDate();
    return dt != null ? new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(dt) : ""; 
}
```

E no action:

```
btSetar.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {

    f.setText(data.getData());
});
```

A validação de null é necessária pois não há data padrão quando o campo é criado, e se tentar recuperar a data com ele vazio, vai estourar exceção.

Comment: vou mudar o nome da classe ! Para que eu possa usar corretamente os metodos da minha classe, o que eu poderia alterar, já que eu ja uso o getDate lá dentro ?

Comment: @Javinha se quiser recuperar a data que foi selecionada no componente, sim. O seu método está criando um datechooser novo e configurando a data atual, ai só vai retornar isso mesmo.

Comment: @Javinha uma duvida que me surgiu aqui, você pretende retornar a data formatada para exibir no campo de texto apenas em formato `dd/MM/yyyy` ou formato timestamp(`Wed Sep 13 16:51:55 BRT 2017`)? Se for o primeiro, acho que minha resposta talvez não atenda, precisaria de uma adaptação.

Comment: queria em formato dd/MM/yyyy, mais a sua resposta ja ajudou, agora como converter, estou procurando.

Comment: @Javinha ah então eu compreendi a pergunta de forma equivocada, vou editar com a solução correta.

Comment: ok obrigado mais uma vez !