# Problemas conversão/formatação de data

Tags: java, data

Estou com problemas para formatar uma data para útil, eu preciso formatar uma data que esta Tue Nov 22 00:00:00 BRST 2017 (exemplo) para data no formato `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Eu andei vendo alguns links, como: [Como converter uma string em data ou date?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108057/como-converter-uma-string-em-data-ou-date) porém não esta dando certo, acredito não estar sabendo usá - los.

```
        Date data = new Date();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(data);

        //eu ultilizo o calendar em alguns calculos, depois eu seto ele no meu pojo.
        //porém ele vem nesse formato, exemplo: Tue Nov 22 00:00:00 BRST 2017
        //quero converter em dd/MM/yyyy
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        meuPojo.setVencimento(sdf.parse(calendar.getTime())); // minha tentativa de converter, porém da erro de: "incompatible types: Date cannot be converted to String"


        //exemplo de como é o meu método setVencimento      


public void setVencimento(Date data){
            this.data = data;
        }
```

Comment: Se o `setVencimento` recebe um `Date` é só passar `calendar.getTime()` pois isso já é um `Date` não há necessidade de fazer parse. Não pode fazer parse de um `Date` que é o que está a tentar fazer

Comment: Um detalhe, quando você faz `new Date()`, está criando um `Date` correspondente à data/hora atual. E ao chamar `Calendar.getInstance()`, está criando um `Calendar` correspondente à data/hora atual. Então criar o `Date` e depois passar para `Calendar` com `setTime` é redundante e desnecessário (só faria sentido se o `Date` não fosse correspondente à data/hora atual).

Answer (score 2):

Se o método espera um tipo `util.Date`, pra que fazer conversão? Passe o `Date` direto pelo método [`getTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime--) da classe `Calendar`, pois ela já retorna um tipo `util.Date` e não precisa nem criar esse tanto de código:

```
meuPojo.setVencimento(calendar.getTime());
```

Se der problemar de tipos incompativeis, cheque os imports se por acaso não está utilizando a classe `sql.Date` ou invés de `util.Date`.

---

Ainda sim, recomendo que aprenda sobre [a nova API de datas do java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/28595), pois ela é bem mais fácil de lidar e é mais precisa.

Comment: não posso passar new Date(), preciso das datas que estão dentro do calendar, ele recebe datas de acordo com algumas condições, por isso tenho que formatar em baixo.

Comment: @Java você não mencionou isso nem no código e nem na pergunta.

Comment: eu escrevi ali em cima, nos comentários do codigo

Comment: @Java então passe gettime direto, o retorno já é um Date.

Comment: mais ai ele me retorna aquela data Tue Nov 22 00:00:00 BRST 2017, ai queria formatar ela em dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: @Java você disse que o método recebe um tipo Date, ele não é formatavel dessa forma. Pra formatar como quiser, precisa converter para string. Da uma lida  [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/234357/28595) para entender melhor.

Comment: @Java o problema não está no `set` mas no sitio onde você escreve/mostra a data. É nesse local que tem de aplicar a formatação. @Articuno Bem interessante essa recomendação de API de datas, que eu pessoalmente não conhecia.

Comment: é que seria mais fácil guardar ela formata ali, o duro de converter pra string, é que ai o setVencimento não vai aceitar ela.

Comment: @Java veja a classe DateHelper que o Victor fez em resposta a um problema que tive [neste post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/122302/28595), provavelmente ela irá resolver seu problema.